# Image not getting referenced from html in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, image, path

In my angular project, I am referencing an image(book.svg) in test.component.html file, which is not working at all. In the console, it references to localhost:4200:/assets/book.svg and hence it is unable to find it

We have kind a different structure of project, with libs and apps as shown.

Please let me know where the problem is and how to fix this.

Have used require() to make it work, but this fails the test cases so not looking for require().

```
<button mat-icon-button >
                <a class="reference-route" routerLink="reference" title="Reference">
                    <img class="reference-image" src="./assets/book.svg" />
                </a>
</button>



the code structure:

project
   ----------apps
       -------------xyz-frontend
           -------------src
               -------------assets
                     ----------book.svg
   ----------libs
       -------------shared
           -------------shared-ui
               -------------src
                    ----------lib
                        ----------test
                             ----------test.component.ts
                             ----------test.component.html
                    ----------assets
                        ----------book.svg
```

```
angular.json

"projects": {
    "xyz-frontend": {
      "root": "apps/xyz-frontend/",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/xyz-frontend/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "apps/xyz-frontend",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "index": "apps/xyz-frontend/src/index.html",
            "main": "apps/xyz-frontend/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "apps/xyz-frontend/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "apps/xyz-frontend/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "apps/xyz-frontend/src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "apps/xyz-frontend/src/styles.scss",
              "libs/shared/shared-styles/src/themes/a4a-theme.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/xyz-frontend/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/xyz-frontend/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz-frontend:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "xyz-frontend:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "xyz-frontend:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "apps/xyz-frontend/tsconfig.app.json",
              "apps/xyz-frontend/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "shared-assets": {
      "root": "libs/shared/shared-assets",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/shared/shared-assets/src",
      "projectType": "library"
    },
    "shared-ui": {
      "root": "libs/shared/shared-ui",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/shared/shared-ui/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "prefix": "xyz",
      "architect": {
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "libs/shared/shared-ui/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "libs/shared/shared-ui/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "libs/shared/shared-ui/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "libs/shared/shared-ui/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "libs/shared/shared-ui/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your import should look like:

```
 <img class="reference-image" src="assets/book.svg" />
```

How's your `angular.json` file `assets` part looks like?

In Angular 6+ it should be like:

```
...
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  // ...
],
...
```

Comment: Hi, I have added angular.json, please check

Comment: Anyway, your import should look like `assets/**/file.extension` because you always start from `assets`. The only thing that is changing is the way you link files and folders to it through your config.